# Maximum likelihood estimate in exponential distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

A postal worker has a service time which is exponentially distributed with density

$$f_{\lambda}(t)=\lambda \cdot e^{-\lambda  t} , t\ge0$$

Given n observations $t_1, ... t_n$ find the maximum likelihood estimate for the unknown parameter ($\lambda$) find the numerical value for (maximum likeliehood estimate)when we have $10$ observed operation times

$$t_i: 1.0, 1.4, 2.0, 0.5, 0.7, 2.0, 1.3, 1.1, 1.8, 0.2$$

where the unit time is one minute. is the maximum likelihood estimate an unbiased estimator for $\lambda$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum likelihood function is given by $$\mathcal L(\vec{t},λ)=\prod_{i=1}^{n}f(t_i\midλ)=\prod_{i=1}^{n}λe^{-λt_i}=λ^ne^{-λ\sum_{i=1}^{n}t_i}$$ The log-likelihood function is given by $$\mathcal l(\vec{t},λ)=\ln\left(\mathcal L(\vec{t},λ)\right)=n\ln(λ)-λ\sum_{i=1}^{n}t_i$$ Setting the derivative of $\mathcal l$ with respect to $λ$ equal to $0$ yields $$\frac{\partial}{\partial λ}\mathcal l(\vec{t},λ)=\frac{n}{λ}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}t_i\overset{!}=0\implies\hat{λ}=\frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}t_i}$$ which satisfies $\hat{λ}>0$ as required. Checking also the second derivative you obtain that in the given $\hat{λ}$ the log-likelihood attains indeed a maximum.

For the given values you have that $$\sum_{i=1}^{10}t_i=12$$ therefore $$λ_{10}=\frac{10}{12}=\frac{5}{6}=0.8333$$ Now, since $E[T]=\frac{1}{λ}$ but $$E[\hat{λ}]=E\left[\frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}t_i}\right]\neq\frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}E[t_i]}=\frac{n}{n\frac{1}{λ}}=λ$$ then the MLE is biased.

Comment: @berg987123 Yes, this is a standard formula. Note that the derivative is with respect to $λ$(!!) so the sum and the n in front of the $\ln$ are treated as constants when we calculate this derivative. It is important to understand this. No, difficult tricks in the derivative... everything but $λ$ is treated as a constant (when we take derivative with respect ot $λ$).

Comment: @berg987123 Oh, that was a mistake :), there shouldn't be a $\ln$ there in the first place.

Comment: Yes, right, λ is the parameter of the distribution and E denotes the expected value. For the derivative, that is simple maximization of a function (first derivative zero, second negative). You need to study the notation and the definitions a little more... Also some theory about random variables. Good luck with it!

Comment: hmm, what is the formula to find the expected value in this question?

Comment: Look here for a concrete calculation http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/100636/bias-of-the-maximum-likelihood-estimator-of-an-exponential-distribution